# how to use embedded expressions for multipart file input in karate

Tags: karate

I need to replace dynamic value 'tenantID' for multipart data input json file. I need to a way to replace a value for multipart input json file.  Below code shows the details:

```
    * def tenantID = '2345'; 
* configure charset = null
Given multipart file properties = { read: 'classpath:ic/feature/REST/TestData/linkedInOauth2RESTInput.json', filename: 'blob', contentType: 'application/json' }
Given multipart file appIcon = { read: 'classpath:ic/feature/REST/TestDataGlobal_Weather.png', filename: 'Global_Weather.png', contentType: 'image/png' }


When method post
```

In the above code I need to replace the 'tenantID' in the 'linkedInOauth2RESTInput.json' file . Since this is multipart input i am not understanding how to replace its content.

Waiting for response.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Peter, I have responded accordingly for those questions now. Please solution  for this .

Comment: just made one edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a Java utility to modify the file `linkedInOauth2RESTInput.json` before you do the upload. You can use the `file:` prefix instead of `classpath:`, so I recommend you save the temp file into the `target` folder, then you can do this:

```
Given multipart file properties = { read: 'file:target/linkedInOauth2RESTInput.json', filename: 'blob', contentType: 'application/json' }
```

But I agree that this is complicated, so I'm making a change to Karate so that you can instead of `read`, pass a `value`.

EDIT: this might also work depending on the server in this case:

```
* def tenantID = '2345';
* def json = read('classpath:ic/feature/REST/TestData/linkedInOauth2RESTInput.json')
* multipart field properties = json
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried * multipart field properties = json this option. But its not working in our server. Only way is as u suggested i will try writing java utility for it.  Its good if you provide this feature in future releases of Karate.

Comment: @Anupama I have already made the fix. it will be available in 0.9.0

Comment: Waw great !  Thank you will test in new build :)

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried in  version 0.9.0.RC5. looks like its not stable as my existing js files are running infinite. After 0.9.0 release i will test.

Comment: @Anupama if you want to ensure that you are able to use 0.9.0 final - PLEASE figure out a way to replicate this problem and file an issue immediately. no one else has reported anything like this.

Comment: @Anupama ... and refer to the release notes: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/v0.9.0

Comment: 1>config details and ssl certificate details(karate-config.js)
2>Login feature file for getting valid cxrf token. this is required for all tests(LoginFinalSub.feature)
3>One test feature file to call all the tests. In this file I am calling login feature file in the background(createRESTApplication.feature). This test file uses the tokens returned by login feature file
4>One main Runner file to trigger all the test feature file(IC_API_Tests_Runner)

When I am running the IC_API_Tests_Runner I am getting infinite loop with 0.9.0.RC5 but this is working fine with 0.8.0.

Comment: I am not able to attach the code sample in the comments section. Hope scenarios are clear.

Comment: @Release of 0.9.0 #UI Automation (experimental).  we will be waiting for it. Like REST API's if this UI automation becomes consistent then KARATE will be big success. Wish you all the best Peter

Comment: @Anupama no, scenarios are not clear. for the last time, please follow this process, else you are on your own: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - all the best

Comment: Hi Peter, Now I have updated to 0.9.0. Now I am observing below error for every feature file which has space and tabs in it.   Is there any known issue to resolve this error as the console errors are going infinite. error is '9:13:04.063 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - <<skip>> feature 14 of 163: classpath:ic/common/resources/getTenantID.feature
line 1:0 token recognition error at: '\r'
line 1:1 token recognition error at: '\n'..........................

Comment: I can see parsing of most of the feature files are skipped in 0.9.0. Please refer below logs   12:46:13.484 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - <<skip>> feature 20 of 163: classpath:ic/common/resources/LoginFinalSub.feature

line 1:0 token recognition error at: '\r'
line 1:1 token recognition error at: '\n'
line 1:0 token recognition error at: '\r'
line 1:1 token recognition error at: '\n'
12:46:13.489 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - <<skip>> feature 21 of 163: classpath:ic/common/resources/stage/changeTheStageName.feature

Comment: Hi Peter,  All my feature files are not parsed in 0.9.0. Parsing is skipped. That is the issue. I wants to know is there any way to force parsing of feature files in 0.9.0 as all these are working in 0.8.0.  Hope now you are clear about my problem space.

Comment: @Anupama no I am not clear. for an example of how other people actually help us solve problems, see this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/615 - if this is so important for your team - maybe you should ask your leaders / other developers to help you.

Comment: Hi Peter ,  This issue got resolved after removing spaces from config file and adding absolute for ssl file in the config file. hence closing issue. thanks for support